# How to prevent asp.net core web api from accessing outside of client application?

Tags: nginx, asp.net-core-webapi, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have asp.net core web api and one client application (angular).

I have deployed both applications to ubuntu using nginx.

I have separated nginx configuration file for both applications.

What I want to achieve is, Only my angular application should be able access API, for everyone else, it should deny to access my API using browser/ their application / postman.

I thought I should be able to achieve this from Nginx Configuration of api. I have simple configuration as below.

```
    server {
        listen        80;
        server_name   api.test.com;
    
        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
}
```

With above configuration , application is working but it allow everyone to access my api outside of client application.

**What I tried to**

I have changed `server_name   localhost` , `server_name   127.0.0.1` also tried to add `allow   127.0.0.1` and `deny   all` but that does not work, I get CORS error in my application.

Please note: with above changes, I have also tried to change in client's base url to `http://localhost:5000` But still I am getting CORS error.

**My questions :**

1. What is correct way to prevent access of api outside of client application?
2. Configure it in nginx is correct way to achieve this? if yes, then what I am missing there? or need to add some code in asp.net core web api project?

**EDIT**
I have already added useCors middleware in my asp.net code as below

```
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();

//only allow from port 4201 and my domain to access otherwise no access
app.UseCors(policy => policy
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .WithOrigins(
                                        "http://localhost:4201",
                                         "https://app.test.com"
                                   )
            );

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
app.Run();
```

Comment: This document about cors may help:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#cors-with-named-policy-and-middleware

Comment: I have already added that in my code, I have updated question, added my source code. but that does not worked as per my requirement . 
My requirement is that I dont want anyone to access http://localhost:5000 itself where api is running.

Comment: Have you registed the service related with cros?and why you configure the policy twice?

Comment: Oh that is with comment, I missed to remove it while copying here. I have updated it in my question